# Django model defining list of URLFields

Tags: django-models, relational-database

I'm pretty new to relational databases and this may be why I'm having this problem but I have a model - Post.

I want it to have variable number of URLs, however Django only seems to have the OneToManyField which requires a model (not a field - which URLField is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relational database design, the fields in a table are always scalar values.  in your case, such a field would 'a url'.  The way you get a collection to apply to a row, you *join* that row with the rows of another table.  In django parlance, that would mean that you need two models, one for the `Post` objects, and another that links multiple urls with that post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pass

class Url(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)


myPost = Post.objects.all().get()
for url in myPost.url_set.all():
    doSomething(url.url)
```

Now you can access urls through a `urls` member

But if you want to get the admin page for Post to also let you add urls, you need to do some tricks with [InlineModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Post(models.Model):
    pass

class Url(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)


class UrlAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Url

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UrlAdmin]

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks TokenMacGuy, So all the Post needs is to be referred to in ForiegnKey? Like, I don't have to explicitly define the relationship from with Post?

Comment: That's right.  there'd be no way of referring to a collection of elements without that reference itself being a collection.  The relational model has a different way of handling that, and this is reflected in the django ORM.

Comment: Hmm. Is the Django Admin supposed to be able to deal with that? 'Cause right now it looks like it added a single URLField form. =/

Comment: Hey again TokenMacGuy, I really appreciate the help. Got it all working, though I note that the admin always has +3 URLFields than I have filled in. Not an issue though.

Comment: Oh, for the sake of anyone who comes accross the same problem, you have to iterate over myPost.url_set.all() rather than myPost.url_set.

Comment: heh, that'll teach me to post code without testing it.   fixed.

Comment: The number of blank fields is configurable with the `InlineModelAdmin.extra` (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra) parameter.  set this to zero to have no extra fields.

Comment: Just to follow up 12 years later, is there any better way to store list of URLs in one model ?