# Django URLfield st

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to build Django Models with Django rest_framework serializers.
Models should store list of URLs searched by a user and the serializer should help return combination of those urls.
Got it to work based on [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#inspecting-relationships) and two answered questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902863/django-model-defining-list-of-urlfields), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework)), but cannot figured how to get a desired formatting: unpack a list of dictionaries inside returned rest_framework response.

Current api output looks like that:
[image]

What I would want is for `links` to be just a list of urls instead of dictionaries.

models.py (short version):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Combo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='searches')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class ComboLink(models.Model):
    combo = models.ForeignKey('Combo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='links')
    link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ComboLinkSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ComboLink
        fields = ['link']

class ComboSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    links = ComboLinkSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Combo
        fields = ['user', 'id', 'created', 'links']
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a variable called links:

```
links = response["link"]
```

You can iterate through this list of objects and make a list:

```
my_list = []

for l in links:
    links.append(l["link"])
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion inside `ComboLinkSerializer` and got an error `ListSerliazer is not iterable`. It would be nice just to iterate over data in `link` but calling `links.data` returns an empty list